# How can I binary compare two large files in Windows?

Tags: windows-7, comparison

I have two 4GB temporary files.

I did a quick visual inspection using a hex editor and see they appear to be the same. Is there a command I can use in something like PowerShell to binary compare the two so I can be certain they are the same?

Comment: Answer: http://www.cjmweb.net/vbindiff/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @dhiwakar-ravikumar already [answered](https://superuser.com/a/816075/366630), you can use the "[file compare](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/fc)" (`fc`) Windows command to compare 2 files (or sets of files), and use the `/b` parameter to do a binary comparison.

However, it should be noted that contrary to the "cmd" command shell, **in PowerShell**, the command has to be spelled out as **`fc.exe`** to avoid the "`fc`" alias to `Format-Custom` to take precedence.
Like so:

```
fc.exe /b [<Drive1:>][<Path1>]<FileName1> [<Drive2:>][<Path2>]<FileName2>
```

Also note that if the extension of the files to compare is one of `.exe`, `.com`, `.sys`, `.obj`, `.lib` or `.bin`, a binary comparison is performed by default and the `/b` parameter can be omitted to the same result.

Comment: I initially tried to edit @dhiwakar-ravikumar 's answer to include the `.exe` extension to the command for PowerShell (which OP specifically asked about) and update the documentation link, but it was rejected as deviating too much from the original answer intent, so I tried to post it as a new answer as I think it is relevant information (someone even asked in a [comment](https://superuser.com/questions/816071/how-can-i-binary-compare-two-large-files-in-windows/816075#comment2138963_816075)). When downvoting, I'd sincerely appreciate info on why and / or advice on a better couse of action.

Comment: Hi desseim, thanks for your answer. I came back to this and found out that YEAH powershell won't take fc and your answer has a heck of a lot more information. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

There is a command in Windows which can give you a binary comparision of two files

```
fc /b <filename1> <filename2>
```

For more information - 
https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/fc.mspx?mfr=true

This works equally well on Windows 7

If you're looking for tools , there is an answer already - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166697/tool-for-comparing-2-binary-files-in-windows

Comment: What about Win10? The 1st link also does not exit any more!

Answer (score 0):

Internal compare tool of Total Commander 64bit works fine on files over 2GB. (File -> Compare by content)

Answer (score 0):

fc.exe works great in PowerShell but just for completeness, I'm adding the PowerShell docs version of compare below:

```
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $(Get-Content textout.txt) -DifferenceObject $(Get-Content textout1.txt)
```

Comment: How would you use it to compare binary files ? As is it treats them as text (and outputs the whole binary "garbage"). I tried the `AsByteStream` parameter  mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Get-Content?view=powershell-7) but it was *very* memory hungry and inefficient (I didn't get it to terminate comparing ~1MiB files on my setup, even after several minutes).

Comment: @desseim Uh oh, I guess I'll have to look into it and update!