# Why do duplicate files have different checksums?

Tags: deduplication

I am trying to remove hundreds of duplicate .PST files from a single folder containing archived .PST files from Outlook. I've tried a couple of Duplicate Remover apps, which rely on checksums to determine equivalency, with the same result: what are clearly duplicated files have different checksums. I have been led to believe that simply having a different title shouldn't alter the checksum. What causes the different checksums?

Subset of files from the .PST directory showing duplicates:

```
12/15/2021  09:01 AM        96,011,264 11_SonyArchiveFolderBackup Repaired (2).pst
12/15/2021  09:01 AM        96,011,264 11_SonyArchiveFolderBackup Repaired.pst
12/15/2021  09:01 AM       111,756,288 11_SonyArchiveFolderBackup.pst
12/15/2021  09:01 AM           271,360 12-4_Inbox - Copy (2).pst
12/15/2021  09:01 AM           271,360 12-4_Inbox - Copy (3).pst
12/15/2021  09:01 AM           271,360 12-4_Inbox.pst
12/15/2021  09:02 AM        21,857,280 12_SonyPersonalFolderBackup (10).pst
12/15/2021  09:02 AM        21,857,280 12_SonyPersonalFolderBackup (11).pst
12/15/2021  09:02 AM        21,857,280 12_SonyPersonalFolderBackup (12).pst
12/15/2021  09:02 AM        21,857,280 12_SonyPersonalFolderBackup (13).pst
12/15/2021  09:02 AM        21,857,280 12_SonyPersonalFolderBackup (14).pst
12/15/2021  09:02 AM        21,857,280 12_SonyPersonalFolderBackup (2).pst
12/15/2021  09:02 AM        21,857,280 12_SonyPersonalFolderBackup (3).pst
12/15/2021  09:02 AM        21,857,280 12_SonyPersonalFolderBackup (4).pst
12/15/2021  09:02 AM        21,857,280 12_SonyPersonalFolderBackup (5).pst
12/15/2021  09:02 AM        21,857,280 12_SonyPersonalFolderBackup (6).pst
12/15/2021  09:02 AM        21,857,280 12_SonyPersonalFolderBackup (7).pst
12/15/2021  09:02 AM        21,857,280 12_SonyPersonalFolderBackup (8).pst
12/15/2021  09:02 AM        21,857,280 12_SonyPersonalFolderBackup (9).pst
12/15/2021  09:02 AM        21,857,280 12_SonyPersonalFolderBackup - Copy (2).pst
12/15/2021  09:02 AM        21,857,280 12_SonyPersonalFolderBackup - Copy (3).pst
12/15/2021  09:02 AM        15,508,480 12_SonyPersonalFolderBackup Repaired (2).pst
12/15/2021  09:02 AM        15,508,480 12_SonyPersonalFolderBackup Repaired.pst
12/15/2021  09:02 AM        21,857,280 12_SonyPersonalFolderBackup.pst
12/15/2021  09:02 AM           525,312 13-6_Inbox - Copy (2).pst
12/15/2021  09:02 AM           525,312 13-6_Inbox - Copy (3).pst
12/15/2021  09:02 AM           525,312 13-6_Inbox.pst
12/15/2021  09:03 AM       145,785,856 13_DellEmailBackup (2).pst
12/15/2021  09:03 AM       145,785,856 13_DellEmailBackup (3).pst
12/15/2021  09:03 AM       145,785,856 13_DellEmailBackup (4).pst
12/15/2021  09:04 AM       145,785,856 13_DellEmailBackup (5).pst
12/15/2021  09:04 AM       145,785,856 13_DellEmailBackup - Copy (194117045).pst
```

It seems clear to me that the archives titled "SonyPersonalFolderBackup (*).pst" are copies of the original. Note the byte counts are equal.

I've not been allowed to post confirmation of the different checksums for each file but, trust me, they are different.

Why is this, and what duplicate removal strategy, excluding name-based, would help me to delete them?

Thanks

Comment: Most likely the metadata (when it was created, etc.) is different enough to give a different checksum but not enough to change the filesize. As for duplicate removal I only would know how to do it named base. Such as using `grep` to find "(" and deleting the files it finds. Good luck!

Comment: As nAZklX says they may be nearly identical with only some data changed. If so you will need to do some kind of binary file comparison to find out what has changed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166697/tool-for-comparing-2-binary-files-in-windows and also https://superuser.com/questions/816071/how-can-i-binary-compare-two-large-files-in-windows

Comment: Are you going to force me to admit I'm not using linux??? I'll see if I can get it done with Select-String in windo$e cmd line. I'll also try the COMP cmd as suggested above. thanks.

Comment: Databases (like the PST file format) are often segmented into “pages”. So they can contain (as of yet) unused areas. That’s why the contents can differ substantially but the size remains the same.

Answer (score 6):

> what are clearly duplicated files have different checksums.

If they have different checksums, they are clearly *not* duplicated.

It is possible that *different* files have the *same* checksum (in fact, since there are a finite number of checksums but an infinite number of possible files, there *must be* an infinite number of different files that have the same checksum). But it is not possible for identical files to have different checksums.

> What causes the different checksums?

The cause of the checksums being different is that the files are different, not duplicates.

> It seems clear to me that the archives titled "SonyPersonalFolderBackup (*).pst" are copies of the original. Note the byte counts are equal.

The byte counts of a file containing the string `hello` and a file containing the string `bybye` are also equal, yet clearly, the two are not identical.

> Why is this, and what duplicate removal strategy, excluding name-based, would help me to delete them?

First, you need to define what you mean by "duplicate". Obviously, your definition of "duplicate" is different from the definition of the tool you are using (which probably uses the definition that "duplicate" means "identical"). Since you consider files to be duplicates that are clearly not identical, you need to define *what* you consider duplicates.

If *you* don't know what you consider a "duplicate", then you also can't define a command which knows that.

Answer (score 1):

Simple - they are NOT (anymore) equal. They probably were at some time, but have been changed later. This seems very strange, unless you consider the extension - these are Outlook Mail files.

**Whenever Outlook opens a .pst file, it writes a time stamp and other things into it!**

You can easily test this by making a copy of a PST and compare them - they are equal. Now open one (or both) with Outlook, and close them - they are no longer equal.

This is a very annoying behavior of Microsoft Outlook, and also the reason you cannot open any write-protected PST files with Outlook - it is so insistent of timestamping them, that it does not even display the content if they are write-protected. As a further consequence, if you have automatic backups, all PST files are considered 'changed' continuously, and result in many MB or GB senselessly being re-backuped every day. Microsoft OneDrive disallows syncing PST files for this exact reason.

Answer (score 0):

eol issues could also be a culprit.  if you're dealing with binary files like jpgs or mp3s this shouldn't be an issue even with different file names.  But any sort of text file or source code file could have crlf or lf as their line endings.  Tabs may have been replaced with spaces. Any of these differences will cause different check-sums.

Answer (score 0):

Old question maybe, but the files can be compared without using a third party program.

To verify that the files are identical, using the command window:

```
FC /B path1 path2
```

Any differing bytes will be listed.
If any bytes ARE different, then the checksums WILL be different.

`FC` is DOS/Windows File Compare, the `/B` means do a binary compare.

Answer (score -1):

So...the solution to the problem stemmed from collecting the multiple backup files..the ***identical copies***...into a common directory, thereby appending a "(*)" to each of the copies...making the file names different, and changing the checksums.

Thanks.

Comment: Checksums are done on the contents of a file, not metadata such as the file name.

Comment: This sounds like a "feature" of whatever tool you use to create the checksums. It would be good for you to tell us what program you are using and how you are using it.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for your interest. I put a sample file in a directory, copied and pasted the copy into the same directory, which renamed the copy. I right clicked in win10 and used the CRC SHA feature from the context menu to use the "*" option to calculate all varieties of the checksum for both the original and copy.

Comment: If you appended `(*)` to the end of one file's contents, but not another file's contents, they are now different.  If you appended `(*)` to the end of a filename, you have an issue, because Windows does not support asterisks in filenames (they are reserved for wildcards).  In the latter case, even if a Windows filename could include an asterisk, changing the filename would not change the file's checksum unless the checksum program, for some odd reason, also includes the name of the file when calculating the checksum.